# Media queries issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have seen this question is asked so often, i have tried all possible ways but my custom media queries are not working, it always pick following media query if screen size is bigger than 768px.

```
@media all and (min-width:768px){
//further code here
}
```

i tried adding following meta tags but found no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

I am writing my media queries in following manner

```
@media all and (min-width:768px){
//further code here
}
@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px){
//further code here
}
@media all and (min-width:1025px) and (max-width:1440px){
//Further code here
}
@media all and (min-width:1441px) and (max-width:2560px){
//Further Code here
}

//Working Code of Media Query for my Screen Size
@media all (max-width:1440px){
  .border-center{
  background-image: url(../img/ms-border-to-centerp.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:155px;
}
.searched-border-center{
  background-image: url(../img/ms-border-to-centerp.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:183px;
}
.mosquePage{
  background-image: url(../img/ms-border-to-centerp.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:183px;
}
#flipbook{
position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#flipbook1{
position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
  .compass_container {
    left: -34% !important;
    top: -34% !important;
    transform: scale(0.8) !important;
}
    
    .mainCompass{
        /*left:-45px; */
    }
    .compass__rose{
    height:250px !important;
    }
    .compass__pointer{
    height:250px !important;
        width:250px !important;
    }
    #qiblaDegree{
    margin-top:0px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried to turn around the order? the first is the last, and the last is the first?

Comment: does it make any difference ??

Comment: yea it could make the difference

Comment: I have tried that too, still facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

It's because the styles are being applied to any size above `768px`.  Either use `max-width` or add `!important` to any styles you want to take precedence over any others. `max-width` is the better choice as adding `!important` can quickly get confusing and messy.

Comment: I changed my code to `@media all  and (max-width:768px)
@media all  and (max-width:1024px)
@media all  and (max-width:1440px)
@media all  and (max-width:2056px)`
Its working in all other browsers but not in Internet Explorer

Comment: It's likely an issue with some specific styles then. Could you include a demo of what's wrong?

Comment: i have edited the question and put some code for you, i am using same code with different sizes for elements

Comment: My bad luck, Media Queries are working but i have 3 Divs and  other divs are shown over 1st Div i need
`[First Div] [Second Div] [Third Div]`
while i receive
[First (secon div) (third Div) Div]